# How to add a desirable phase shift in the input from 3-phase ac mains?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, rectifier, mains, power-electronics, three-phase

I want to build a 12 pulse rectifier circuit. I know delta-wye or wye-delta transformers can be used to add phase shifts equal to the multiples of 30, but I don't want to use transformers. Is there another way to generate the needed phase shift?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to avoid transformers? Cost? Size? Just to see if you can?

Comment: size is the major issue, there's already a transformer in the circuit following the rectifier but it's a high frequency and single phase transformer so it's smaller in size,, If i use transformers in the rectifier they would be low frequency(50Hz), 3-phase and probably 2 in number, which demands a huge volume,

Comment: What voltages and currents are we talking about? And where's the DC ultimately going?

Comment: input is from the mains(about 220rms-line to neutral), DC is going into a switched-mode-power-supply with output 10-60 volts(DC) and current up to 30 amps.

Comment: At this point I'm more asking for curiosity than anything, but why use a twelve-pulse rectifier at those power levels? I understand the goal of a twelve-pulse is to reduce the harmonics and capacitor ripple. Are those a problem for you as low as 1.8 kVA?

Comment: Actually I'm going with 6-pulse bridge rectifier but I was curious if there's another way to achieve phase shifts without transformers,

Comment: In this sort of application, why wouldn't you use a modern [3-phase PFC](http://www.pes.ee.ethz.ch/uploads/tx_ethstudies/Kolar_Essence_Three-Phase_PFC_02.pdf) (power factor correction) circuit?